# How to customize woocommerce product order email table?

Tags: php, email, templates, woocommerce, html-table

I am beginner in woocommerce and I have removed Quantity column with their value from email template that is /themes/mytheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php & /themes/mytheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php
by simply comment  as below code

```
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>

        <!--<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>-->
        <th></th>
        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

[image]

And after

```
<tr>
        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>

        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php /*_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); */ ?></th>

        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    </tr>
```

Looks Like

[image]

Comment: Instead of commenting the whole line, just remove the part between PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

Delete complete price html code and php code:

```
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

Comment: @Pravin, what if you delete complete code, like above?

Comment: Thnaks..My problem has been solved it was due to rowspan attribute of next row.